# Call a function from thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am using the below code to call a method from thread function.It's not working.Please help me to do this.

```
DataTable dt = get_data(Convert.ToInt32(Start_From), Convert.ToInt32(End_To));
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
  ThreadStart newThread = new ThreadStart(delegate { insert_Data(dr); });
  Thread myThread = new Thread(newThread);
}

public static DataTable get_Data(int form,int to)
{
   .....
   return Dt;
}

[MTAThread]
public static string insert_Data(DataRow dr)
{
 .....SOme code here //This funcion not call 
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `Queue` to relay data to a thread pool. Your code will start a thread for each row which is very inefficient.

Comment: Am new for this concept.Give me some idea.

Answer (score 2):

You made two mistakes:
 - You forgot to start the thread (as said in any answer)
 - You are using a closed value. This bad behavior, because the thread function will receive the wrong row. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    DataRow localRow = dr;
    ThreadStart newThread = new ThreadStart(delegate { insert_Data(localRow); });
    Thread myThread = new Thread(newThread);
    myThread.Start();
}
```

To create a thread for a small operation is not recommanded. Try using the threadpool, for performance:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    Action<DataRow> action = (row) => insert_Data(row);
    action.BeginInvoke(dr, null, null);
}
```

Another solution is it use PLINQ:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), dr => insert_Data(dr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the thread as well by calling myThread.Start();

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
  DataRow dataRow = dr;
  ThreadStart newThread = new ThreadStart(delegate { insert_Data(dataRow); });
  Thread myThread = new Thread(newThread);
  myThread.Start();
}
```

When a thread is constructed it is not initially running; you need to do this explicitly using the Thread.Start method. This gives you a bit more control over when the thread begins execution.

Edit: fixed for using a closed value.

Comment: Will not work. The values closed inside the delegate will cause problems.

Comment: What is running very slow? How slow? Anyway, the slowness has nothing to do with the question you asked originally. You probably need to post another question if you have a problem with the performance.

Comment: @OP: Yes, this is very slow. Creating and starting a new thread is pretty slow (milliseconds). Check out my answer for more performance.

Answer (score 0):

1: Why would you want to start a thread for each data row you find?
2: To start the thread in your code you need to add the following line of code

```
 ....
 ....
 ThreadStart newThread = new ThreadStart(delegate { get_Data(dr); });
 Thread myThread = new Thread(newThread);
 myThread.Start();
```